# Why isn't my airflow task being scheduled?

Tags: airflow

I work in a team that uses one of the big cloud providers to host the stuff that we do. Every morning before I come into work I have a scheduled job that stands up a development environment within that cloud and every evening I have a scheduled job that tears it all down again. That development enviornment includes an instance of Apache Airflow and another thing that job does is run an Airflow DAG which contains one task.
I have an intermittent problem with that DAG, the DAG will run but occasionally the task instance for that one task fails to get scheduled. It has happened this morning, here are the task instance details:
[image] 
In this case:

- the scheduler is running and is definitely not under heavy load (nothing else is running)
- as far as I'm aware it has not already ran

I have an easy way of fixing this, I go and restart the airflow scheduler (which, because we have setup airflow to run as a linux service, involves ssh'ing onto the VM on which we have airflow installed and issuing `systemctl restart airflow-scheduler`). Immediately after doing this the task instance will begin to execute.

As I said this problem is intermittent i.e. I cannot determine the root cause, some mornings everything works fine, sometimes it gets stuck like this.This morning it is stuck.

I have read [Why isn't my task getting scheduled?](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-my-task-getting-scheduled) and one thing there that piqued my attention was:

> Is your start_date set properly? The Airflow scheduler triggers the task soon after the start_date + schedule_interval is passed.

I have just had a look at the task and its `start_date` is `None`:
[image]

The `schedule_interval` of the DAG is `None` because we don't schedule this DAG, we manually trigger it (which is what my morning job does):
[image]

So, the task doesn't have a `start_date` and the `schedule_interval` of the DAG is `None` which sort of explains why its not running, but it doesn't explain why some days it does run and some days it does not.

I have just gone and restarted the scheduler service (as explained above) and the task is now running. Taking a look at the details of the task instance again, it now gained a `start_date`:

[image]

I'm not clear on why restarting the scheduler causes the task instance to start running. Can anyone suggest what might be the cause? I admit I don't have a great understanding of `start_date`.

UPDATE 2020-04-21: A colleague brought to my attention a bug that sounds similar (though may not be the same): [AIRFLOW-1641 - Task gets stuck in queued state](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1641). That issue was fixed in airflow 1.9, we are currently using airflow 1.8.1 but will soon be upgrading to airflow 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, restarting the scheduler shouldn't change the start date of the dag. I'm wondering if you have a small logic bug in your job that initially create the airflow instance and dag. It sounds like everything would work fine if your dag had a start date to begin with. Them you wouldn't need to dive into why restarting the scheduler gets it to work.